# fieldChanged function in netsuite

Tags: netsuite

Field Changed Function
    If the value in a text field is changed to the same value (example: old value = "ABC", new value = "ABC"), will the script
    Field Changed Function fire or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nlapiSetFieldValue](http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/resources/APIs/Dynamic%20HTML/SuiteScriptAPI/MS_SuiteScriptAPI_WebWorks.1.1.html)

Some additional information:

**FieldName**:

> *String* - the name of the field being set
>
> *value*: String - the value the field is being set to
>
> *firefieldchanged*: Boolen - if true then the fieldchange script for
>   that field is executed. (Only available in Client SuiteScript)

Sets the value of the given field.
This API can be used during beforeLoad scripts to initialize field scripts on new records or non-stored fields.
nlapiSetFieldValue is available only in Client and User Event SuiteScripts.

Whenever you are changing the value of an `textfield`, you will call the fieldChanged event even if you are staying with the same name as you had before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the Client Side script event Field Change, if I recall correctly this will only trigger when the user has changed the value of the field in the UI.  But this event can also be triggered by the nlapiSetFieldValue and nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue if the fireFieldChange parameter is set to True.